# windowTranslucentStatus in android Lollipop version is completely removing status bar from the screen

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying achieve Gmail like Navigation drawer(Drawer over toolbar but under status bar). Drawer is appearing like I want but status bar is not visible. I have already searched a lot but didn't find right solution.

My v21\styles.xml style is

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
            <item name ="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
            <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        </style>
```

style.xml is

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: this is how it looks

Comment: there is no status bar here

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but I can clearly see the status bar